# SOT limit of Self-adjoint operators is self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis

Say $T_n$ is a sequence of self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space and converges in the strong operator topology to $\mathcal{T}$, must $\mathcal{T}$ be self-adjoint? Since $T_nx$ converges to $\mathcal{T}x$ in norm, it converges weakly, and so I figured that

$\langle\mathcal{T}x,x\rangle-\langle x,\mathcal{T}x\rangle=\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle T_nx, x\rangle-\langle x, T_nx\rangle=0,$

which does the job, but there's a chance that my limit operators aren't justified.

Thanks.

Comment: You've got no reason to worry; everything's correct in your solution.

Comment: Does this statement remain true when SOT is replaced by the norm topology?

Comment: @eatfood Yes, since convergence in norm topology implies convergence in SOT, simply because $\|T_nx - Tx\|\leq\|T_n-T\| \ \|x\|$.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. Your assumptions are $(T_nx,y)\longrightarrow (Tx,y)$ for all $x,y$ (sot hence wot limit). And $(T_nx,y)=(x,T_ny)$ for all $x,y$ and all $n$ (self-adjoint). So 
$$(Tx,y)=\lim (T_nx,y)=\lim (x,T_ny)= (x,Ty)$$ 
for all $x,y$. That is: $T$ is self-adjoint. The first and the third equalities are from the wot condition. The middle equality is by self-adjointness of each $T_n$.